# Как вставить src одного изображения другому?

Tags: javascript

Как вставить src первого попавшегося изображения из `<div class="imgs-container">` другому с классом `<img class="empty-src">`?
При этом не должно быть привязки ко вложенности изображений, они могут быть помещены ещё в какие-либо контейнеры, но нам необходимо ориентироваться от `<div class="imgs-container">`.

```html
<img src="" class="empty-src">

<div class="imgs-container">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-banana/55914/x25BrmbsGrQHgP0c4vOE7g4sO_banana_20161021_11.png/orig">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-banana/55914/x25BrmbsGrQHgP0c4vOE7g4sO_banana_20161021_11.png/orig">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-banana/55914/x25BrmbsGrQHgP0c4vOE7g4sO_banana_20161021_11.png/orig">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('img.empty-src').src = document.querySelector('div.imgs-container img').src;
```

```html
<img src="" class="empty-src">

<div class="imgs-container">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-banana/55914/x25BrmbsGrQHgP0c4vOE7g4sO_banana_20161021_11.png/orig">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-banana/55914/x25BrmbsGrQHgP0c4vOE7g4sO_banana_20161021_11.png/orig">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-banana/55914/x25BrmbsGrQHgP0c4vOE7g4sO_banana_20161021_11.png/orig">
</div>
```